# Applying a php if statement to another if statement?

Tags: php, if-statement

I want the if statement below to appear only on certain pages (for instance, I don't want them to surround the whole structure if this is an user page):

```
    <div class="mainbar">

    <?php if /* I don't want this and... */ ( bbp_has_topics( $bbp_loop_args ) ) : ?>

        <?php while ( bbp_topics() ) : bbp_the_topic(); ?>

            <div class="topic-wrapper">
                <div class="topic-left">
                    <h2><a href="<?php bbp_topic_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php bbp_topic_title(); ?>"><?php bbp_topic_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    <span><?php printf( __( 'Started by: %1$s', 'bbpress' ), bbp_get_topic_author_link( array( 'size' => '14' ) ) ); ?></span>

                    <?php if ( !bbp_is_forum() || ( bbp_get_topic_forum_id() != bbp_get_forum_id() ) ) : ?>
                        <span class="bbp-topic-started-in"><?php printf( __( 'in: <a href="%1$s">%2$s</a>', 'bbpress' ), bbp_get_forum_permalink( bbp_get_topic_forum_id() ), bbp_get_forum_title( bbp_get_topic_forum_id() ) ); ?></span>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php bbp_topic_tag_list(); ?>

                </div><!-- #topic-left -->

                <div class="topic-right">
                    <div class="topic-like-count">
                        <h4><?php // bbp_topic_reply_count(); ?><?php if(function_exists('the_ratings')) { the_ratings(); } ?></h4>
                        <span><?php _e( 'likes' ); ?></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="topic-reply-count">
                        <h4><?php bbp_topic_reply_count(); ?></h4>
                        <span><?php _e( 'replies' ); ?></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="topic-freshness">
                        <h4><?php bbp_topic_freshness_link(); ?></h4>
                            <span>
                                <?php bbp_author_link( array( 'post_id' => bbp_get_topic_last_active_id(), 'size' => 14 ) ); ?>
                            </span>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- #topic-right -->
            </div><!-- #topic -->

        <?php /* this to appear in an user page */ endwhile; ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

        </div><!-- #mainbar -->
```

This is the if statement I should use to make sure that the if statement above don't surround the whole structure in an user page:

```
<?php if ( ! is_single( 'user' ) ) : ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

But I have no idea how or where to place it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @phant0m the if statement `<?php while ( bbp_topics() ) : bbp_the_topic(); ?>` shouldn't surround the whole structure only in certain pages. Some pages only work if the structure don't have that if statement.

Comment: "the if statement: while" - what's a while statement? So basically,y ou want certain control structures to only work on certain pages. You need to check for them. Assuming you have an array of allowed sites and a variable with the current site: `if(in_array($site, $allowed_sites) && (<other conditions>) )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can simply replace:

```
if ( bbp_has_topics( $bbp_loop_args ) ) :
```

by:

```
if ( is_single( 'user' ) || bbp_has_topics( $bbp_loop_args ) ) :
```

This way, the second condition is applied only if the first condition is `false`.